# VS2010 change Path Macro

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

Hi I have a VS2010 projekt witch i moved from one machine to another. And on the new machine the QT installation is in a different place.

Now the projekt can´t find the QT headers and libs. When i look in the projekt properties I see that all QT path are set with the makro $(QTDIR) and this path is the path of the old machine. 
Is there any way to change the value of the makro?

THX for help

[image: prop manager]

Answer (score 3):

There is such thing as User Macros in VS 2010. It can be defined in Property Sheets. To find it you should open `View->Property Manager` panel, and there you'll see your projects and configurations. It will look like this:

[image]

In my project, I have a `foldernames` property sheet, in QT the name might be different. So you should right-click the property sheet and you'll see `User macros` page under `Common properties`:

[image]

Check there for your `QTDIR` macro.

Comment: Hi thx for your reply but i dont have such a folder i only have microsoft.cpp.win32.user application and core windows libraries. only in the first one i´m able to edit and there the macro for qt is allready set

Comment: You shouldn't have "foldernames" property sheet. In your case the name of the property sheet is different. Could you look at your Property Manager panel (it's not Solution Explorer!) and post what do you have there?
It shouldn't matter what kind of application do you have.

Comment: i put the image to my main question because i don´t know how to add it in this comment

Comment: Got it. Just make sure you've tried all these 3 sheets for user macros, if you haven't already. If it doesn't help, I have no further ideas:(

Answer (score 2):

I believe QTDIR is system/user variables that you need to define on your Windows.
You can take a look at : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519 that explain how to set the value.

Or, you can take a look at: http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html

Once you set the variable, you may need to restart visual studio

To check if the variable has been set, type the following in command prompt:
*echo %QTDIR%*

Comment: Hi thx for your reply but it´s not the user variable. The user variable is on both machines set to the correct directorie